# Is this an acceptable use case of the ternary operator?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I was using the ternary operator to perform a very simple, conditional action. It worked well, but my IDE (PHPStorm) reported it as an error. The error I got was:

`'void' method 'performAction' result used`

The code I was using is this:

```
($this->doThis ? $class->performAction() : $class->performDifferentAction());
```

The error in PHPStorm is obviously wrong; I'm not using the result of the void method anywhere. I'm just calling the methods and that works as expected. I just used the ternary operator as a short-hand for this:

```
if($this->doThis)
{
    $class->performAction();
}
else
{
    $class->performDifferentAction();
}
```

I think this looks like a valid use case for the ternary operator. It's not obfuscated, easy to read and short.

Is this a design flaw nevertheless?

Comment: It does not look like a valid case - a *conditional operator* is supposed to return something somewhere.

Comment: And where can I find that obligation?

Comment: It's not obligation, it's a common sense. Expression must return a value, by definition. If I were a code reviewer for that line - I wouldn't let it pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary operator is an *expression* which returns a *result*. Its purpose is to be used when an "inline condition" is needed which would otherwise require you to create one or two additional variables. As such, whenever you use a ternary operator, you're kind of expected to use its result.

For example, you wouldn't write this, would you?

```
1 + 2;  // result not used, does nothing
```

What you're essentially doing there is write such code, but add a *side effect* to it:

```
1 + someFunc();  // soooo... does this do anything?
```

Your IDE therefore urges you to explicitly write side-effect code using `if..else`. It more directly expresses what you're doing there.

Having said all that, it's ultimately up to you and your style. PhpStorm has its preferences; if you want to override them, switch off that particular inspection. However, that inspection is there to help you write better code; it would warn you if you *really forgot* to assign a return value somewhere.

Comment: There's a difference between your 2 examples and mine. Your code doesn't _do_ anything; mine does. (Well, `someFunc` may do something, but the `1 +` is obviously useless. There's no 'useless' code in my snippet.)

Comment: That's exactly the point, *does* `1 + someFunc()` *do* something or not? The return value isn't used, so it does nothing... or does it? Your code is the same: `$foo ? 1 : bar()`. Sooooo.... is there simply a typo and you forgot to use the return value, or does `bar()` have a side effect...? That's all a lot more explicit if you write `if ($foo) bar()`.

Comment: "is obviously useless" --- and if it was a programming language that accepts operator overloading? Would it make more sense for you?

Comment: @Sherlock Don't miss the addition in my last paragraph. Those inspections are there to help you write better code and nag you when you *may* be committing an error. In this case it can't tell whether it's an error or on purpose, and it nags you about it. It's a good idea to write "textbook code" which passes all validations, they're there for a purpose. Being clever and cutesy rarely results in better code. Writing textbook code may be boring and "verbose", but the purpose of code is to get stuff done and be readable, not to exercise the language syntax.

Comment: @deceze I agree! That's why I'm asking here. It didn't look so wrong to me, but surely the IDE reports it for a reason. I'm still not completely convinced, but I already changed my code to the more explicit variant before posting this question.

Comment: @Oli I still fail to see why this is unreadable, but a normal ternary operation isn't.

Comment: Because nobody writes it that way, hence you are not used to seeing it like that, so it takes longer to parse.

Comment: @Sherlock why not? That code **may** cause side effects.

Comment: @Oli: "you are not used to seeing it like that, so it takes longer to parse." --- additionally to this 110% correct phrase: when you see something strange you start thinking that it was done with some special purpose and spend even more time decyphering it.